# Simple Servlet and Nullpointerexception (error 500)

Tags: java, exception, servlets

I get following error after trying to launch my first servlet... what may be wrong? I am using proper method (get) and the same code works for my friend... is it possible to be tomcat's fault?

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Ciastko threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

DOGET method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws    ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      HttpSession sesja = request.getSession(true);
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      String login = request.getParameter("login");
      String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
      if(login.isEmpty() || pass.isEmpty()){
           out.println("Brak sesji lub atrybutu.");
          } 

      if(login.equals("admin") || pass.equals("admin")){
           out.println("ADMIN");
          } 
      else{
       sesja.setAttribute("login", login);
       sesja.setAttribute("pass", pass);
      }



}
```

and here is index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Tytuł</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Ciastko" method="GET">
<p>Login: </p><input name="login" id="login" />
<p>Hasło: </p><input name="pass" id="pass" />

<input type="submit" value="Wyślij!" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how did you define the servlet? edit and add your web.xml or @servlet definition please

Comment: can you show the full stack trace ?

Comment: well the problem I see is that after starting it it automatically "runs" form button. So it always started it with null form values, and that is why there was an exception. When I changed method to:

       ` if(login==null || pass==null){
          out.println("NO ATRIBUTE");
         } `

It does not even print the form from index.html, but automatically the NO ATTRIBUTE text... what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [ServletRequest.getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String))
>
> Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or **null if the parameter does not exist.**

You're not checking your login/pass for null, which will make `isEmpty` crash if the parameters are not set.

Comment: well the problem I see is that after starting it it automatically "runs" form button. When I changed method to:

       ` if(login==null || pass==null){
          out.println("NO ATRIBUTE");
         } `

It does not even print the form from index.html, but automatically the NO ATTRIBUTE text... what may be wrong?